# How to horizontally scroll through element with overflow: hidden on mobile device

Tags: html, css

This has been driving me crazy for the last few hours.

Basically in the design I'm coding responsively there is a box, and the data goes across it horizontally, the box has `overflow: hidden` so you can see there is more text in the box but it's just hidden. The aim is to be able to just push down with your finger on a mobile device, swipe to the side and it will show more of the hidden content but it's not working.

Here's the jsiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8L5v4/2/

Any help would be great thanks.

**UPDATE**
I know I can use `overflow-x: scroll` but that shows a scroll bar and the client does not want the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow-x: scroll` and you can style the scrollbars that result:

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

```
// CSS selectors to target
::-webkit-scrollbar             
::-webkit-scrollbar-button      
::-webkit-scrollbar-track       
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb       
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner      
::-webkit-resizer
```

[image: Webkit scrollbar selectors visualized]

Most mobile browsers are Webkit, so this should work alright (if not, could you specify which browsers you need to target?). The guys at Webkit also have an article on styling scrollbars:

https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

In particular, "The `display` property can be set to `none` in order to hide specific pieces."

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x:scroll`

```
#fixed-dimensions {
   width: 130px;
   height: 60px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Check this updated link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/8L5v4/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
#fixed-dimensions {
width: 130px;
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 60px;
}
```

The Scroll can be assigned for both x and y axis separately with the help of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` CSS property.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L5v4/4/)